# Building radios using RLC Meter

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation, passive-networks

I'm interested in building AM and FM radios from discrete components. Has anyone ever used an RLC meter to precisely create the inductors and other elements used in these radios? I know cheaper RLC meters measure parameters at 1kHz to 10kHz (100kHz if lucky). Is this still applicable and useful in trying to create the right components for the radios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create IF transformers that resonate at 455kHz (AM) or 10.7MHz (FM), and RF transformers at 500-1600kHz (AM) or 88-108MHz (FM), and oscillator coils at RF+IF. So, no.